# How to remove ExchangeActiveSyncDevices child object without exchange installed

Tags: windows, active-directory, exchange-2010, windows-sbs-2011

We've recently migrated to Server 2016 from SBS 2011.  We disabled / removed 90% of Exchange under the previous SysAdmin so unfortunately there are a few issues.

We have come across these when setting up Azure AD Sync for Office 365.

There are Sync errors occuring for the users that had ExchangeActiveSyncDevices on the old local exchange server.  This fortunately is only 5 of us, but we need to fix it.

Using both ldp.exe and ADSI Edit you get an access denied error when trying to remove the child object.

Is there a way to forcefully remove these child objects without exchange being installed?

Cheers.

Comment: Did you tried ADUC via Domain admin? Normally the child object is visible here and you can delete it as well (not really recommended by Microsoft).

Comment: You cant see it under ADUC.

Comment: sure you can, I just created an screenshot for you inside my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use ADUC to delete the elements (its not recommended, but might work for you). You need to use the "view -> users, Contacts, Groups, and Computers as containers" option:

[image]

Then the ActiveSync elements will show:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you are a domain admin, an access denied is not going to stop you; chances are permissions are restricted on those objects... but you can still take ownership of them and change their permissions to give you full control, then delete them.

What's more important, you should make sure all of your user accounts have been properly cleaned of all Exchange-related attributes before trying to sync them with Office 365.